# SQL procedure-trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes comunidad,
Apoyo con el siguiente problema.
tengo un procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[asignarPropuesta]
@fechaActual date
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE PropuestaEconomica set Vigente = 1 where (SELECT CONVERT(date,FechaAplicacion)) = @fechaActual
END
```

El cual envía bit: 1 a la fila vigente cuando la fecha es actual, este se genera en un hangfire cada semana buscando si existe una propuesta con la fecha actual para asignarla como vigente.

En tabla donde ocurre el update tengo un trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_PropuestaEconomica]   
ON [dbo].[PropuestaEconomica]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
Declare @fechaActual date = GETDATE();
    IF(UPDATE(Vigente))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PropuestaEconomica set Vigente = 0 where CONVERT(date,FechaAplicacion) != @fechaActual
    END
END
```

Este trigger despues de un update en columna vigente todo lo que no corresponde a fecha actual pasa vigente=0.

| Id | Fk_Usuario | FechaAplicacion | Vigente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 219 | 107 | 2021-10-24 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 220 | 107 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 221 | 107 | 2021-07-20 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 222 | 110 | 2021-07-20 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 223 | 111 | 2021-07-08 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 224 | 111 | 2021-08-22 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 225 | 120 | 2021-12-24 00:00:00.000 | 0 |

Ejemplo tabla correcto suponiendo fecha actual = 2021-08-22 00:00:00.000.

Es la idea, pero:

-si un usuario no tiene una fecha reciente en su propuesta.. debería quedarse vigente la anterior hasta que se le asgne una actual o en su caso puede siempre se quede con esa.
Pero esta forma me cambia todo siempre.
Cual ayuda para investigacion se agradece.
Saludos!

Comment: creo que tu problema es que en tu trigger actualizas todo, y no deberia ser así, debes validar por cada ítem que se actualizo únicamente y a eso realizar el update, validando contra la tabla Inserted, que es la que tiene cada registro de lo que se modifico.

Comment: ??

`ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_PropuestaEconomica]   
ON [dbo].[PropuestaEconomica]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 IF((select Vigente from inserted)= 1)
 BEGIN
 UPDATE PropuestaEconomica set Vigente = 0 where Id != (select Id from deleted) and Fk_Usuario = (select Fk_Usuario from deleted)
 END
END`
Me funciona pero cuando son fechas repetidas, crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu trigger solo deberia actualizar a cada ítem que haya sido afectado en tu operación, y lo que haces ahorita es afectar a todo.

Este es el ejemplo de como lo manejaría con tus reglas actuales,

- Validar tabla propuestas vs Inserted, por usuario (solo los usuarios afectados, en tu Sp y segun tus reglas).
- Validar que este vigente el registro y que la fecha sea diferente a la actual (No se si tienes que validar que sea menor o mayor).

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_PropuestaEconomica]
ON [dbo].[PropuestaEconomica]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS BEGIN
    Declare @fechaActual date = GETDATE();
    UPDATE P
    set P.Vigente = 0
    FROM PropuestaEconomica P
        INNER JOIN Inserted I on P.Fk_Usuario=I.Fk_Usuario
    WHERE  P.Vigente  = 1 
        and CONVERT(date, P.FechaAplicacion) != @fechaActual
END
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado tu propuesta.
 cualquier detalle seria modificar tu qwerty. Gracias nuevamente.